# Create discord channel with specific roles js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Admin");
message.guild.channels.create(
  channelName2, 
  {
    type: "GUILD_TEXT",
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: myRole.id,
        allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"],
      },
      {
        id: myRole.id,
        deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Bot creates the text channel but has no permissions edited and it ignored almost whatever I write in "id: XXXXXX"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you are editing the permissions,

First you edit it to allow

```js
    {
        id: myRole.id,
        allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"],
      }
```

Then you edit to deny permissions

```js
      {
        id: myRole.id,
        deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"]
      }
```

However by doing it twice you undo the permissions of the first time, the correct way to do it would be by making it into one object:

```js
message.guild.channels.create(
  channelName2, 
  {
    type: "GUILD_TEXT",
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: myRole.id,
        allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"],
        deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Nothing, I tried it and still ignored permission changes

Comment: That code should work. It could also be that since you allow ``VIEW_CHANNEL`` and then deny ``VIEW_CHANNEL`` taht it's only going to execute on of them

Comment: yeah, it was my bad, every code I tried for the last like 10 hours worked, but since I was using setParent to move categories it would autoreset permissions every fking time.
Fixed it by using {lockPermissions: false}